# mongodb continueOnError not suppressing duplicate key errors

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongojs

I am trying to keep a collection with unique keys. Data to be inserted comes from various distributed places (although individual documents are immutable), and could possibly contain duplicates. I was hoping to simply insert records and suppress duplicate key errors using `continueOnError`, but the duplicate key error is still thrown. The code looks like this...

```js
fetchStatuses(statusId)
  .then(results => connection
    .then(db => db.collection('statuses').ensureIndex({id: 1}, {
      unique: true, dropDups: true
    })
      .then(() => db.collection('statuses').insert(results, {continueOnError: true, safe: true}))
      .then(response => {
        winston.info(`Inserted ${response.insertedCount} statuses into mongo`);
        return results;
      })
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try an unordered insert like described in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#perform-an-unordered-insert):

> The following example performs an unordered insert of three documents.
>   With unordered inserts, if an error occurs during an insert of one of
>   the documents, MongoDB continues to insert the remaining documents in
>   the array.

```
db.products.insert(
   [
     { _id: 20, item: "lamp", qty: 50, type: "desk" },
     { _id: 21, item: "lamp", qty: 20, type: "floor" },
     { _id: 22, item: "bulk", qty: 100 }
   ],
   { ordered: false }
)
```

As far as I understand the docs, there won't be thrown an error in this case but instead there is set a special property of the result object

> If the `insert()` method encounters a non-write concern error, the
>   results include the `WriteResult.writeError` field

```
WriteResult({
   "nInserted" : 0,
   "writeError" : {
      "code" : 11000,
      "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.foo.$_id_  dup key: { : 1.0 }"
   }
})
```